# Echarts3.0 display percent on y-axis in stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, vuejs2, echarts, yaxis

Using Echarts3.0 in Vuejs2.0 component, I am trying to assign percent on y-axis in  a stacked bar chart. I tried boundaryGap, splitnumber,  etc, but none of them worked.
But i cannot achieve it, Anyone has idea how can i get % on y-axis?

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    loading: true,
    bar: {              
    xAxis:  {
            type: 'category',
            data: ['Location1','Location2']
        },
    yAxis: {
            type: 'value',
           splitNumber: 10,
           boundaryGap: ['0', '100%'],
           min:0,
           max:100,
            scale:true,
            splitArea : {show : true},
            label: {
                 formatter: function(){
                 return 100 * value /$(this.axis.tickPositions).last()[0]                              
                 + '%';
                       }
                   }
            },
     series: [
            {
                name: 'Location1',
                type: 'bar',
                stack: 'one',
                label: {
                    normal: {
                        show: true,
                        position: 'insideRight'
                    }
                },
                data: [1100, 2050]
            },
            {
                name: 'Location2',
                type: 'bar',
                stack: 'one',
                label: {
                    normal: {
                        show: true,
                        position: 'insideRight'
                    }
                },
                data: [291064, 34789]
            }
        ]
        }
```

})

Answer (score 11):

Set yAxis in below format

```
yAxis: [{
  type: "value",
  name: "%",
  axisLabel: {
    formatter: "{value} %"
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to calculate maxValue first, then...

```
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value',
      axisLabel: {
        formatter: (value) => {
          return Math.floor(100 * value / maxValue) + '%';
        }
      }
    }
  ],
```